# How do I make a sprite "stand' on another sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've got two sprites that can detect collisions, but I'm not sure how I can make my character sprite "stand" on my platform. Nothing I've done seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects, you can move the 2nd rectangle on the 1st rectangle by setting the `bottom` of the 2nd rectangle with the `top`  of the 1st rectangle. With the virtual attributes of `pygame.Rect` it is easy to do so:

```py
rect2.bottom = rect1.top
```

Or if you have 2 [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects:

```py
sprite2.rect.bottom = sprote1.rect.top
```

---

If you have 2 [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) objects (`surf1` and `surf2`) and the 2 corresponding positions (`x1`, `y1`) and (`x2`, `y2`), use [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) to create `pygame.Rect` objects from the *Surfaces*. Move the 2nd rectangle on the 1st rectangle and update the position of the 2nd rectangle:

```py
rect1 = surf1.get_rect(topleft = (x1, y1))
rect2 = surf2.get_rect(topleft = (x2, y2))

rect2.bottom = rect1.top
y2 = rect2.y
```